# jquery sortables in a responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, responsive-design

I have a 3 column layout that folds down to one column. I want to be able to move div's between the columns. The problem I have is a soon as a column is empty there is no way to move a div back into it.

see here (move all divs into one column): http://jsfiddle.net/65ENw/17/

Putting a fixed width on the columns solves this, but then my layout stops being responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a min-height and min-width on the columns and they will still occupy space when they have no widgets in them.

```
.widgetCol{ margin:0 1% 0 1%; width:98.0%; min-width:20px; min-height: 20px}
```

I have updated your fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/65ENw/18/

Comment: the problem with this is when the layout collapses for smaller screens the forced min height breaks the layout - i.e there will be an extra 20px between the widgets